# How to add numbers in Excel in the same row and separate them by 'suffix'?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a list with more than 700 entries (see the picture below).

In row 'B' there are some numbers that have suffix "KM", "KN" or "E".

Is there some formula(or any solution) that can add these numbers but in the same time to separate these 3 suffixes(not to add them together, but to separate "KM", "KN" and "E"), so the solution can be something like:

```
 1. 345 KM
 2. 220 KN
 3. 560 E
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The below formulae should be able to split the numbers and the suffixes found in column B:

```
=LEFT(B1, 0, FIND(" ", B1))
=LEFT(B1, FIND(" ", B1)+1, 9999)
```

If you wanted to avoid VBA, you could use DSUM. I've never actually used it, but I know it can be useful for this type of thing. Hopefully that points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Data \ Text to Columns` to split your column based on the `space` character, then pivot your data and use the Unit (KM, KN, E) as a row field and the number as a data field.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **B1** , in **C1** enter:

```
=--MID(B1,1,FIND(" ",B1)-1)
```

and copy down.  In **D1** enter:

```
=MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1)+1,999)
```

and copy down

Finally to get the sums, use formulas like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C:C)*(D:D="KM"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to add each type of suffix together.

Simplest way is to separate the numbers into its own column.
You can enter `=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(B1,SEARCH(" ",B1)))` in cell **C1** and copy down for each row to accomplish this. Then use a `SUMIF` function to get the results.

- **KM:** `=SUMIF(B1:B999,"=*KM",C1:C999)`
- **KN:** `=SUMIF(B1:B999,"=*KN",C1:C999)`
- **E:** `=SUMIF(B1:B999,"=*E",C1:C999)`

Comment: Warning: numbervalue will only work in excel 2013 and excel online, use `=--(LEFT(B1,SEARCH(" ",B1)))` if you're in a prior version.